# "CryptographicException: Cannot find the requested object" while the certificate file exists

Tags: c#, cryptography, x509certificate

I have a `.p12` certificate file and I create my certificate like this:

```
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(certFileLocation, "mySecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
```

When `certFileLocation` is on my desktop and I give the absolute path, the code works. But when I put the entire content of the .p12 file in a new file in my solution and set the `Copy to Output Directory` property of the file to *"Copy if newer"* I get a `CryptographicException` exception that says:

> Cannot find the requested object

I also check every time whether the file is in place and it is. What is the difference between these two scenarios and why can't I read the file with the latter approach?

Comment: What is the value of `certFileLocation`? Also when you get the exception are you running, debugging or testing (MSTest) the code?

Comment: `certFileLocation` will be the location of the `p12` file. This happens when I am debugging.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem.  It worked with a fixed file but did not work with the file relative to my unit tests.  This was so mindnumbling that I finally had a look at the files and compared them binary.  They where *not* the same.  They were read and written as strings, which caused them to be slightly different due to unicode interpretations. When I copied them myself (from a resourcestream) as binary (byte[]), everything worked again.  I hope this solves your problem too.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MS-test, you need a couple more bits:

1. make sure your `runsettings` are configured to **NOT Delete Folders** after tests are complete if you want to see any output after-the-fact; this caused me 30 minutes of lost time!
2. add the `DeploymentItem` attribute to your `TestMethod`.  this gets it copied to your `Out` folder.
3. use the `TestContext.DeploymentDirectory` as your "root" folder:

   ```
   X509Certificate2 GetCert()
   {
       var stx = File.Open(Path.Combine(TestContext.DeploymentDirectory, "thecertfile.pfx"), FileMode.Open);
       using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(stx))
       {
           return new X509Certificate2(br.ReadBytes((int)br.BaseStream.Length), "password");
       }
   }

   [TestMethod, DeploymentItem("thecertfile.pfx")]
   public void Signing_FlameTest()
   {
       var cert = GetCert();
       Assert.IsNotNull(cert, "GetCert failed");
   }
   ```